# trouble installing packages in RHEL 5.3

Tags: installation, svn, packages, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to install rabbitvcs, a subversion GUI tool. http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/fedora.

```
[foo@bar conf]# yum install nautilus-python pysvn python-configobj python-devel dbus-python python-dulwich  meld
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package nautilus-python available.
No package pysvn available.
No package python-configobj available.
Package python-devel-2.4.3-24.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python-devel-2.4.3-24.el5.i386 already installed and latest version
Package dbus-python-0.70-7.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package python-dulwich available.
No package meld available.
Nothing to do
[foo@bar conf]# yum install nautilus-python pysvn python-configobj  python-dulwich  meld     Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package nautilus-python available.
No package pysvn available.
No package python-configobj available.
No package python-dulwich available.
No package meld available.
Nothing to do

[foo@bar conf]#
```

Now, what do I need to do to get these packages ? I guess my organization wants to save on RHEL license/support costs and isn't providing me the package repositories. Are there alternate repositories from where I can download and install packages ? If yes, how do I go about it ?

I am a native windows user and trying to switch to linux and I've been frustrated by the lack of installers that install all the dependent software/packages. Pls. help me.

Thank you,

**UPDATE**

```
[foo@bar adminui]# rpm -Uhv http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-xfer.YB9Xj9: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 217521f6
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:epel-release           ########################################### [100%]
[foo@bar adminui]# yum install nautilus-python pysvn python-configobj  python-dulwich  meld
epel                                                                                              | 3.7 kB     00:00     
e2b838eb24c31d9faac525f1415ded1297c7f659-primary.sqlite.bz2                                       | 3.7 MB     00:01     
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package nautilus-python available.
No package python-dulwich available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pysvn.x86_64 0:1.6.2-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package python-configobj.noarch 0:4.6.0-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package meld.noarch 0:1.1.5-5.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=========================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                   Version                          Repository                Size
=========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 meld                             noarch                 1.1.5-5.el5                      epel                     797 k
 pysvn                            x86_64                 1.6.2-1.el5                      epel                     359 k
 python-configobj                 noarch                 4.6.0-1.el5.rf                   rpmforge                 234 k

Transaction Summary
=========================================================================================================================
Install      3 Package(s)         
Update       0 Package(s)         
Remove       0 Package(s)         

Total download size: 1.4 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/3): python-configobj-4.6.0-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm                                                 | 234 kB     00:00     
(2/3): pysvn-1.6.2-1.el5.x86_64.rpm                                                               | 359 kB     00:03     
(3/3): meld-1.1.5-5.el5.noarch.rpm                                                                | 797 kB     00:04     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                     99 kB/s | 1.4 MB     00:14     
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 217521f6
Importing GPG key 0x217521F6 "Fedora EPEL <epel@fedoraproject.org>" from /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing     : pysvn                                             [1/3] 
  Installing     : python-configobj                                  [2/3] 
  Installing     : meld                                              [3/3] 

Installed: meld.noarch 0:1.1.5-5.el5 pysvn.x86_64 0:1.6.2-1.el5 python-configobj.noarch 0:4.6.0-1.el5.rf
Complete!
```

---

I was able to install pysvn, meld and python-configobj packages. but it could not install  nautilus-python and python-dulwich.

What should I do now ?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those are in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). Give that a try first.

Comment: thank you very much.I'm a linux noob. Can you guide me how to get EPEL on my box ? how do I know which version of EPEL is on my box ?

Comment: The EPEL major version used must match the EL major version, so you want EPEL 5. The article linked to links to the various `epel-release` packages; simply download and install the appropriate one.

Comment: I was able to install pysvn, meld and python-configobj packages. but it could not install  nautilus-python and python-dulwich.

What should I do now ?

Thanks again.

Comment: also, I'm asking another question out here which you might be able to answer. http://superuser.com/questions/387308/how-to-update-svn-package-on-rhel-5-3

Comment: It looks like they're *supposed* to be in EPEL, but are not. I'd poke the bug reports to see where they're at. [nautilus-python](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=235189), [python-dulwich](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=605423)