# how to update svn package on RHEL 5.3?

Tags: svn, updates, packages, rpm, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have 1.4.2 version of svn on my RHEL 5.3 box. I tried updating and I get the following message. What should I do ?

```
[foo@bar adminui]# svn --version
svn, version 1.4.2 (r22196)
   compiled Sep  1 2008, 06:38:03

Copyright (C) 2000-2006 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_dav : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV (DeltaV) protocol.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme

[foo@bar adminui]# which svn
/usr/bin/svn
[foo@bar adminui]# yum update svn
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

I need to get to 1.6.x version of svn to get my work done.

## **UPDATE1**

```
[foo@bar target]# yum update subversion
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

How can I trick the "yum" tool to go fetch the right version of subversion ?

## **UPDATE2**

```
# yum repolist
repo id              repo name                                status
adobe-linux-i386     Adobe Systems Incorporated               enabled :      17
base                 Base Repo for 5.30-5Client - x86_64      enabled :   1,953
desktop-install      Recurring Desktop installs               enabled :       0
desktop-update       Recurring Desktop updates                enabled :     143
engineering-install  Recurring Engineering installs           enabled :       0
engineering-update   Recurring Engineering updates            enabled :      42
epel                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 -  enabled :   6,897
google               Google - i386                            enabled :       5
google64             Google - x86_64                          enabled :       4
rbel5                RBEL 5 Repo                              enabled :     197
rpmforge             Red Hat Enterprise 5.30 - RPMforge.net - enabled :  11,020
vt                   Base Repo for 5.30-5Client - x86_64      enabled :      40
workstation          Base Repo for 5.30-5Client - x86_64      enabled :   1,205
```

I removed a few organization specific repos from the above listing for privacy/security.

What should I do to update subversion to the latest version?

**UDPATE 3**

I found that our admins have the latest version of svn at  /usr/corp/bin. Thanks for your answers and time :-)

Answer (score 2):

The package is called "subversion", and is at version 1.6.11.

Comment: thank you.

[root@abacchu-lnx target]# yum update subversion
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
[root@abacchu-lnx target]#

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'trick' yum tool to do anything. To answer your question, updating the `subversion` package is as simple as `yum update subversion`. The latest version of svn in RHN 5 repo is 1.6.11-7. If that dosn't work check if you have registered `yum repolist`.

Also patch your Linux box to RHEL 5.7, you are way behind my friend.

Comment: pls. see UPDATE2 in the question. RHEL 5.7 : the software we're developing is targetted at 5.3 and hence we need to test for 5.3. "yum update subversion" : pls. see Update1 above. Thank you. Any further ideas ?

Comment: Your other option then is to compile svn from source, I had the same issue with an outdated git client on RH5.

Comment: thank you. will try that. <rant>Why doesn't Linux have windows style INSTALLSHIELD setups that install all the dependencies ?</rant>